# Wordpress how to display the all children of a child page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, children

I'm using the below to list all child pages of the current parent page. I now need to list and child of the children pages... That may be confusing..

Get current page ID > Display all direct children of that page ID > I now need to also display the current pages children's children...

So like:

```
 - Child page 
   - Child of Child page
   - Child of Child page
 - Child page
```

```
<div class="nav-col">
    <?php 
    global $post;
    $direct_parent = $post->post_parent;
    ?>
    <div class="side-nav">
    <?php 
    wp_list_pages(array(
        'child_of'    => $direct_parent,
        'title_li' => ""
    ));
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_list_pages` takes an argument called "depth". You could use that to solve your problem.

Values you could assign to "depth":

- -1 (any depth)
- 0 (all pages)
- 1 (top-level pages only)
- n (pages to the given n depth)
- Default 0

```php
<div class="nav-col">
  <?php 
    global $post;
    $direct_parent = $post->post_parent;
  ?>
  <div class="side-nav">
  <?php 
    $args = array(
      'child_of'    => $direct_parent,
      'title_li'    => "",
      'depth'       => -1
    );
    wp_list_pages($args);
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/